# Get inherited caller type name in base static class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

i have:

```
class parent
{
    public static string GetTypeName()
    { 
        /* here i want to get the caller's type
        So child.GetTypeName() should display "child" */
    }            
}     

class child : parent { }

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(child.GetTypeName());
}
```

Is it possible somehow to get the caller's type in base class?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get caller's type in base class?' Get the name of the base type from the inheriting type, right?

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can it by looking up the stackframes / stacktrace, but this is a very hacky approach, and not recommended. Var better to use a virtual method or `GetType()`

Comment: noo, in main() it should display : "child".

Comment: or the name of the inheriting type, inside a method on the base type?

Comment: Ahhh, now I see what you mean... just because is dawned on me - and no, to answer your question, at least not easily at all.

Comment: Marc Gravell - yes, I found that hack, not like it.  I think there is no good slution,but maybe somebody here, on SO knows more :)

Comment: What was wrong with the regular `GetType()`? I assume you're trying to do something more in your code than you're showing us here?

Comment: @klm_: Why can't you use `typeof(child).Name`?

Comment: @max: because `Parent` is unaware of `Child` in this sense, and this method can be called publicly, so the caller may not be a `Child`.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: but caller will always explicitly know about `Child` and can write `typeof(Child)` istead of `child.GetTypeName()`.

Comment: @Cody Gray: this is all i need. frankly

Comment: @max: However, the question states: 'get the caller's type in base class', which implied that if type `Grandchild` called the method it would print the type name of such. Regardless, seems he figured out what was needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible unless you pass the caller to the method (as an argument) or walk the stack frame to get the caller.

The compiler substitutes `parent` for `child` when calling `parent`'s static methods through the `child` type. For example, here's the IL code for a call to `child.GetTypeName()`:

```
IL_0002:  call   class [mscorlib]System.Type Tests.Program/parent::GetTypeName()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `this.GetType()` will do this. But can't check at the moment.

(assuming you want the child's type in the parent's method.)

Comment: There is no `this` in a static method.