# C# get caller class type (Not in Static)

Tags: c#, inheritance, stack-frame

How do I get the caller class type in the base?

this is the parent, here I want to print the child type without sending it

```
public abstract class Parent: ISomeInterface    {

        public void printChildType()
        {
             Type typeOfMyChild = ?????;
             MessageBox.Show(typeOfMyChild); //how do I get Child typeOfMyChild
        }
}
```

the child

```
public class Child : parent {

}
```

pirnt the child type :

```
Child child = new Child();
child.printChildType();
```

Thanks

(I already saw this one: [Get inherited caller type name in base static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736392/get-inherited-caller-type-name-in-base-static-class) but I am using none static methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Type typeOfMyChild = this.GetType();
```

Thanks to polymorphism when you invoke:

```
Child child = new Child();
child.printChildType();
```

it should print `Child`.

Comment: It's not necessary to make `printChildType` virtual to observe polymorphism here.

Comment: @Ani, correct. Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you just looking for the current type ?

```
    public void printChildType()
    {
         Type typeOfMyChild = GetType();
         MessageBox.Show(typeOfMyChild); 
    }
```